# Doxygen doesn't warn for missing parameter if none is already documented

Tags: c++, doxygen

If I write this (in the class `CPosition`, file `position.h`):

```
/**
 * @brief Constructor
 * @param x x coordinate
 */
CPosition(int x, int y);
```

Doxygen warns me:

```
error: The following parameters of CPosition::CPosition(int x, int y) are not documented:
parameter 'y'
```

But if no parameter is documented in the `CPosition` constructor, like this:

```
/**
 * @brief Constructor
 */
CPosition(int x, int y);
```

Doxygen doesn't warn me at all.

What configuration am I missing if I want doxygen to warn even if no parameter is already documented ?

---

Some relevant configuration directives of my `Doxyfile`:

```
WARN_IF_UNDOCUMENTED   = YES
WARN_IF_DOC_ERROR      = YES
WARN_NO_PARAMDOC       = YES
```

Comment: Are you sure that those are properly set? That is, are you sure you didn't accidentally unset them elsewhere?

Comment: Yes, sadly I'm 100% sure.

Comment: What doxygen version?

Comment: @ArturKink 1.8.11

Comment: This is a bug. The problem is: You only have a \brief description, so detailed description is not being generated, and only during the detailed description phase does it emit the warning you are looking for. You'll notice if you remove the \brief it will give you the warning. The warning you see when you do provide a \param is a separate pass that checks if all \param are correct, but this is never entered if no \param are provided, and the check for if no \param are provided is in the later detailed description phase that is not reached. I'll see if I can fix this or I'll file a bug report

Comment: For now you could set ALWAYS_DETAILED_SEC = YES and REPEAT_BRIEF = YES and that should work

Comment: @ArturKink It works ! :) It looks like you did a lot of work to answer me, thank you very much. Add an answer if you want and I'll accept it.